# How many different types of enemies are in Dark Souls 3?

Tags: dark-souls-3

Don't ask why, but I want to count different types of enemies in Dark Souls 3.

It is easy to use [this wiki](http://darksouls3.wikidot.com/bosses) and count that there are 19 bosses and 4 minibosses. But [usual enemies](http://darksouls3.wikidot.com/enemies) are present at different locations, so it is much harder to count. I wonder if someone has done it or has a link which has enemies listed independently of location, one time per list.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on that wiki page I've prepared a small script which kindly trimmed and deduplicated the names of enemies, and then counted them.

My result is a total of <strike>90</strike> <strike>111 (updated with invaders)</strike> **141** with both DLC's enemies included.

A list of all ordered enemies:

- Alva, Seeker of the Spurned
- Ancient Wyvern (Enemy)
- Angel
- Archive Scholar
- Basilisk
- Bastard Ghru
- Black Hand Kamui
- Black Knight
- Boreal Outrider Knight
- Burning Stake Witch
- Cage Spider
- Carthus Sandworm
- Cathedral Evangelist
- Cathedral Grave Warden
- Consumed King's Knight
- Corpse-grub
- Corvian
- Corvian Knight
- Corvian Peasant
- Corvian Settler
- Corvian Storyteller
- Court Sorcerer
- Creighton the Wanderer
- Crystal Lizard
- Crystal Sage (Enemy)
- Darkwraith
- Daughter of Crystal Kriemhild
- Deacon of the Deep
- Deep Accursed
- Demon
- Demon Cleric
- Demon Statue
- Desert Pyromancer Zoey
- Devout Bomber
- Devout of the Deep
- Drakeblood Knight
- Drang Knight
- Elder Ghru
- Fallen Knight
- Farron Follower
- Festering Starved Hound
- Gertrude's Knight
- Ghru
- Giant Fly
- Giant Slave
- Grave Warden
- Grave Warden Skeleton
- Great Crab
- Great Wolf
- Grotesque Londor Grower
- Harald Legion Knight
- Havel the Rock
- Hawkwood the Deserter
- Headless Gargoyle
- Hollow
- Hollow Assassin
- Hollow Cleric
- Hollow Manservant
- Hollow Slave
- Hollow Soldier
- Holy Knight Hodrick
- Horace the Hushed
- Hound-rat
- Icy Great Crab
- Infested Corpse
- Irithyllian Beast-hound
- Irithyllian Slave
- Irithyllian Soldier Slave
- Jailer
- Jailer Handmaid
- Judicator
- Knight Slayer Tsorig
- Knight of the Deep
- Large Devout of the Deep
- Large Hollow Soldier
- Large Hound-rat
- Large Serpent-man
- Lesser Crab
- Lion Knight Albert
- Livid Pyromancer Dunnel
- Locust
- Locust Spawn
- Londor Pale Shade
- Longfinger Kirk
- Lothric Knight
- Lothric Priest
- Lothric Thief
- Lothric Wyvern
- Lycanthrope
- Lycanthrope Hunter
- Mad Ghru
- Man-grub
- Millwood Knight
- Mimic
- Monstrosity of Sin
- Murkmen
- Overgrown Lothric Knight
- Peasant Hollow
- Pilgrim
- Poisonhorn Bug
- Pontiff Knight
- Praying Hollow Soldier
- Pus of Man
- Ravenous Crystal Lizard
- Reanimated Corpse
- Ringed Knight
- Rock Lizard
- Rotten Flesh of Aldrich
- Rotten Slug
- Sage's Devout
- Sage's Prentice
- Seeker of the Spurned
- Serpent-man
- Serpent-man Summoner
- Sewer Centipede
- Silver Knight
- Silver Knight Ledo
- Sir Vilhelm
- Skeleton
- Skeleton Swordsman
- Skeleton Wheel
- Smouldering Bastard Ghru
- Smouldering Conjurator Ghru
- Smouldering Ghru
- Smouldering Mad Ghru
- Smouldering Rotten Flesh
- Starved Hound
- Stray Demon
- Sulyvahn's Beast
- Sword Master
- Tree Woman
- Unkindled Apprentice
- Unkindled Brigand
- Unkindled Butcher
- Unkindled Drang Knight
- Unkindled Watchdog
- Winged Knight
- Wolf
- Wretch
- Writhing Rotten Flesh
- Yellowfinger Heysel